# how to use VBA created SQL in an Access query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to Access and I think there must be an easy way to do this but I have not found it. I was hoping to use the same access query to produce a detail or summary report based on the user entered parameter. I was thinking of changing the SQL associated with the query in VBA.

1. Is this the best way to accomplish my goal? Or is there a better way?
   If using VBA is the way to go, I did the following:

   ```
   Function ChangeSQL() As String
       Dim strSQL As String

       If [Summary] = -1 Then
           ChangeSQL = "Select LASTNAME, Sum(G.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT " _
                     & "FROM DONOR D, GIFT G" _
                     & "WHERE D.ID = G.DONOR " _
                     & "GROUP BY D.LASTNAME "

       Else
           ChangeSQL = "Select LASTNAME, AMOUNT  AS AMOUNT " _
                     & "FROM DONOR D, GIFT G" _
                     & "WHERE D.ID = G.DONOR "
       End If

   End Function
   ```
2. how do I call the *ChangeSQL* function from the Access query
3. how do I actually execute the changed SQL from the query?

I have seen many examples where the VBA executes the desired SQL, so I know how to do that in VBA but I still have question 2) and I would also like to be able to just use my simple *ChangeSQL* function as written and have the query actually execute the changed SQL (hence my question 3).

Comment: Recommend building report based on non-aggregate query and then use report Sorting and Grouping features with aggregate calcs in Header/Footer sections. Report allows display of detail data as well as summary info. The report Detail section can be programmatically hidden, like: `Reports!reportname.Detail.Visible = False`

Comment: You don't need VBA for this.  You can just [use parameters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-parameters-in-queries-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356) in query criteria, or reference the contents of an unbound (or bound) control in an open form (which will act like an undefined parameter if the form is not open).

Comment: The first step is to create valid SQL - `... FROM DONOR D, GIFT GWHERE D.ID = ...` isn't going to be valid - you need a space before the keyword `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

use the "where" clause, and make the reports sql *without* any parameters, and you not need to change the params or modify the SQL.

So, you can build a un-bound form (a un-bound form is a form that is NOT attached to a table - these forms are typically designed for user interface face stuff like prompts, print buttons etc).

The following screen shots are all un-bound forms, and they simply prompt the user for information.

http://www.kallal.ca/ridesrpt/ridesrpt.html

The above should give you some ideas

So, the solution use now is simply to take the values from the form, and build your own where clause in code. That way, you simply design the reports (or forms), and attached them to the query. And, NO FORMS conditions are placed in the query. And no messy parameters are used (they are BAD because you then have a query with "fixed" parameters - the  where clause eliminates this need and you can THEN use any criteria you want - you not "fixed" to a set of parameters.

To "send" the conditions to the report (or form), you simply use the "where" clause. This is exactly why ms-access has this feature...and it solves a zillion problems...and will reduce your development costs by a substantial amount.

The code to make those above screens work and launch the report with the selected restrictions when you hit the "print" button is easy:

```
dim   strWhere       as string

' user selects sales rep combo

if isnull(cboSalesRep) = false then

   strWhere = "SalesRep = " & cboSalesRep & ""

end if

' user "might" choose a city from a ciby combo

if isnull(cboCity) = false then
   if strWhere <> "" then
      strWhere = strWhere " and "
   endif
   strWhere = strWhere & "City = " & cobCity & ""
end if
```

Note how the 2nd combo test is setup. You can add as "many" more conditions you want. Lets say we have a check box to only include Special Customers. We can add to our very nice prompt screen a check box to

[x] Show Only Special customers

The code we add would be:

```
if chkSpeicalOnly = True then
   if strWhere <> "" then
      strWhere = strWhere " and "
   endif
   strWhere = strWhere & "SpecialCust  =  true"
endif
```

For sure, each combo and control we add to the nice report screen takes a bit of code, but no more messy then the query builder. And this way, each query is nice and clean, and free of a bunch of HIGHLY un-maintainable forms! expressions. And free of those messy parameters.

Even better is if you decide to use SQL server, then you don't have to change your code! (and you can use high speed SQL views with above code).

Further, it means you can re-use the same query for different reports, and have no worries about some form that is supposed to be open. So, a tiny bit more code eliminates the messy query problem.. For me, this is very worth while trade. And you can re-use the query for other parts and again NOT have to supply parameters, or supply any parameter you want.

For a date range, we could put two calendar controls on the screen. The code could be:

```
dim strWhere        as string
dim strStartDate    as string
dim strEndDate      as string


strStartDtae = "#" & format(me.StartDateContorl,"mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
strEndDate = "#" & format(me.EndDateContorl,"mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"

strWhere = "InvoiceDate is between " & strStartDate & " and " & strEndDate

docmd.openReport "InvoiceReport",acViewPreview,,strWhere
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call the function inside of a query. I would continue to let VBA handle the query itself.

```
public Function ChangeSQL(byval Summary as Boolean) as string
if summary = -1 then
    ChangeSQL = "Select LASTNAME, Sum(G.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT " _
              & "FROM DONOR D, GIFT G" _
              & "WHERE D.ID = G.DONOR " _
              & "GROUP BY D.LASTNAME "
Else
    ChangeSQL = "Select LASTNAME, AMOUNT  AS AMOUNT " _
              & "FROM DONOR D, GIFT G" _
              & "WHERE D.ID = G.DONOR "
End If
End Function
```

You didn't need to dim strSQL as string, you aren't using it.

But you can go any number of ways of creating a query in VBA. You can even have the query change fields and tables based on users answers and have 1 function build 1 query without an If statement or a select case.

If you need it to create this query from a button click or afterupdate event, you can always use the DAO library on the form triggering the event.

```
Private sub ButtonClick_Click()
dim qdf as dao.querydef

set qdf = currentdb.createquerydef("NameOfYourQuery",ChangeSQL(-1))
set qdf = nothing
docmd.openquery "NameOfYourQuery", acViewNormal
End Sub
```